# How do I insert a full name into the database?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

How do I insert a full name programmatically, with just three column names in my database?

My database columns is :

```
    FirstName, MiddleName and SurName
```

How do I make the query for a full name to be uploaded to the database but separated when stored inside the database?

Example : I want to upload `Lyndon Broz Canete Tonelete`, but I want it to be stored inside my database separately like...

```
FirstName = "Lyndon Broz"

MiddleName = "Canete"

SurName = "Tonelete"
```

Would it be possible?

Comment: What database? SQL Server or something else?

Comment: How do you decide which word(s) is first, which is middle and which is last name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question concerns this: "How do I separate my first name, middle name, and surname into three columns, and insert it into a SQL database".

Depending on how you look at it, the answer is either highly complicated or extremely simple.

One solution is just to "split" the name into parts and remove whitespace:

```cs
string name = "Lyndon Broz Canete Tonelete";
var parts = name.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// parts[0] = "Lyndon";
// parts[1] = "Broz";
// parts[2] = "Canete";
// parts[3] = "Tonelete";
```

But can you spot the issue? No? OK—I'll help. You see, even though you have divided the name into parts, you cannot know for certain if your first name is "Lyndon Broz", if your middle name is "Broz Canete", or if there is some other constellation of names. Some cultures even put their last name before their first name (e.g. China), so any assumptions you make are bound to fall apart at some point.

A better way is to have three text fields, where the user enters their first, middle, and last name. This eliminates all guesswork, and there is a reason why most services use this model.

```
First name:  [ Lyndon Broz ]
Middle name: [ Canete      ]
Last name:   [ Tonelete    ]
```

From these fields, it's just a matter of inserting these values into your database.

```sql
INSERT INTO People (FirstName, MiddleName, Surname) 
VALUES (@firstName, @lastName, @surname)
```

Comment: yes that's my problem because i couldn't identify which is the `FirstName`, `MiddleName` and the `SurName` of the user.. =(

Comment: And here you have your answer! There is no consistent way of "guessing", so make three inputs for your user.